# Ler dados de uma coluna através do C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho um código postal e dividio em 2 variáveis: a primeira, onde aparecem os primeiros 4 números e a segunda onde aparecem os 3 últimos.

Ex.:

> 4300-234 - primeira = **4300**; segunda = **234**.

Tenho uma tabela na base de dados que tem 3 colunas referentes a códigos postais. A `PC4`, onde aparecem os primeiros 4 números, a `PC3` onde aparecem os últimos 3 e a `Desc`, onde aparece o descritivo correspondente, ou seja, de onde são esses códigos postais.

O que eu preciso é de comparar a minha primeira variável com a coluna `PC4`, comparar a segunda variável com a coluna `PC3` e depois quando as minhas variáveis forem iguais ás colunas `PC4` e `PC3`, quero receber os dados correspondentes da coluna `DESC`.

Comment: Mas em que momento você quer fazer isso? Numa _query_ direto no banco? Executar uma _query_ pelo seu código C# usando algum ORM ou a `SqlCommand`? Por favor, seja mais específico.

Comment: Quero fazer isto no código c#

Comment: É algo que nunca fiz, já pesquisei e não consigo perceber como fazer

Comment: Ok, tudo bem que você não saiba, mas pelo menos se esforce um pouco para nos explicar **como quer fazer** isso.

Comment: Eu tentei explicar o melhor que consegui. Tenho 2 variaveis, variavel1 tem os 4 primeiros numeros do codigo postal, a variavel2 tem os ultimos 3. Preciso de comparar a variavel1 com a coluna PC4 e a variavel2 com a PC3, quando a variavel1 = PC4 e variavel2 = PC3, quero receber o valor da coluna Desc (que é a cidade onde pertence o codigo postal)

Comment: Vamos tentar de novo. Você sabe fazer conexão com o banco de dados? O seu projeto já faz conexão com o banco?

Comment: Sim, ja tenho tudo conectado, ja inseri valores na base de dados atraves do c# e tudo.

Comment: Ok, chegamos na parte que eu queria. Como é que você insere (e lê) dados do banco?

Comment: através de INSERT e SELECT

Comment: Ok, ok, vamos tentar de novo. Que você faz select e insert eu sei, afinal não tem outra forma natural de se fazer isso. Agora, o que eu quero saber é: **qual é o código que você usa para fazer um select no banco de dados**?

Comment: @Dc poste o código, leia isto e reformule a pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, veja que é uma recomendação do Help oficial do site e não minha. Assim você evita da sua pergunta ser fechada

Comment: @jbueno o problema é esse ! nao sei como formular o meu codigo para fazer um select !

Comment: @DC Você já consulta algum dado no banco. Não consulta?

Comment: @jbueno A unica coisa que fiz neste projeto foi inserir dados na base de dados

Comment: E qual é o código que você usa para "inserir dados na base de dados"?

Comment: conn.Open();
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tabela(coluna1, coluna2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)";
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa é uma ideia de como você pode fazer, existem n formas de se fazer, acredito que você consigo retornar alguns dados para ir testando.

Dentro do select você pode implementar uma cláusula WHERE onde você retornará somente os registros que satisfizerem aquela condição. O retorno da comparação adicionei em uma variável, você pode adicionar em uma lista ou fazer alguma operação caso seja necessário.

Na parte da comparação passei um tipo Int32 sem saber qual é o seu valor de fato, ai você precisa adequar o código para sua necessidade.

```
public void SelectDescricao()
{
    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Sua string de conexão"))
        {
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT coluna1, coluna2, coluna3_Descricao FROM Tabela", conn))
             {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.CommandText;

                using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (rd.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (rd.Read())
                        {
                            if( variavel1 == Convert.ToInt32(rd["coluna1"].ToString()) && variavel2  == Convert.ToInt32(rd["coluna2"].ToString()))
                            {
                                varDescricao = Convert.ToInt32(rd["coluna3_Descricao"].ToString());                                        
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
        }                         
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        // tratamento da exceção
    }
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isto que eu precisava ! Já ajustei o código à maneira que eu precisava, muito obrigado !

Comment: @DC, que bom que ajudou. Abraço

Comment: Ajudou bastante ! Abraço

Comment: já agora, tenho outra duvida, talvez me possa ajudar

Comment: @DC, diz ai. Qual sua dúvida ?

Comment: consegue ver as minhas outras perguntas ? eu fiz uma pergunta nova. Está lá a minha duvida